# Screenshot taken using Selenium and Chromedriver in Task Scheduler is Blank/Black

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, screenshot, scheduler

I'm using Selenium to automate Google Chrome to take screenshots. And I use Task Scheduler to run this application automatically at specified time daily.
The problem is that the screenshots taken is blank/black. However, if I manually run this app by double click its icon, the screenshots gotten is good.
The version of Selenium and Google Chrome I used is all the latest stable. Selenium 2.35 and Google Chrome 29. And I am using C# bindings.
Anyone knows what's wrong with Task Scheduler and how to fix this blank/black screenshot issue?

Comment: See if this post helps you.  That person has a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654382/getting-blank-black-screenshot-with-automated-screen-capture-using-task-schedu

Comment: I've read that post. It doesn't help. Thanks however Noobacode.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you recently update the version of your Selenium? The ChromeDriver 2.x has an issue with blank screenshots: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=309.

Comment: Yes I updated both the Selenium and ChromeDriver to latest to be compatible with Chrome 29. However I'm not using a VM and not RDC connection related, so considered it as a separate issue.